# Why won't my stockpiles show up?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've been having a bit of trouble with stockpiles being ignored, so I checked to see if they were actually there in the first place. I had read that stockpiles counted as rooms, so I went to view rooms/buildings. The only thing there was the wagon. Am I doing that wrong? If not, does anyone know why they won't create and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Stockpiles are not counted as rooms, they're more like "areas". They're created from a different menu, they don't require a piece of furniture to be started, and you can freely design them square by square instead of spreading in all directions like rooms.

To query an already created stockpile, use the <kbd>q</kbd> key

Comment: Specifically, stockpiles are created via 'P', and rooms are created via 'i'. (It's been a while, so these might actually be the wrong keybindings, but the point is, you don't create them the same way)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yes, I didn't think of putting that in but I really should.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: 'p' (lower case) is stockpiles, 'i' lowercase) is for zones (pasture, garbage dump, etc.). Most rooms are created using an installed piece of furniture; a bed for bedrooms, armor stand or weapon rack for barracks,  table for dining room, chair for office, etc.